# Onto and everywhere defined for functions having same cardinality

Tags: functions

I was reading about function and I came across this text,

> If A and B have same number of elements and particularly if A = B then we only need to
>   prove one of either onto or everywhere defined to prove that it is a
>   bijection.

Now I don't get this point. I will be thankful if someone can **elaborate** this with an **example**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true for infinite sets.  Take $A=B=\mathbb{N}, f(n)=2n$.  This is everywhere defined and one-to-one but not a bijection.  For finite sets it is not true, either.  You need onto or (everywhere defined and one-to-one).  Otherwise, take $A=B=\{1,2\}, f(1)=f(2)=1.$  Given either onto or everywhere define and one-to-one, let $n=|A|=|B|,$ draw two sets of $n$ dots (like I did in a previous question) and connect them.  If it is onto, you have to have $n$ distinct function values, so all $n$ elements must have defined values, and they must all be distinct.  If it is everywhere defined and one-to-one, you have $n$ distinct values.